# Lower bound on building heap.

Tags: reference-request, computer-science

A lower bound of the needed number of comparision to build a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) is given by [GASTON H. GONNET and J. IAN MUNRO](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0215068) as following

> THEOREM 4. $1.3644... n + O(lg n)$ comparisons are necessary, not only in the worst
>   case, but also on the average to create a heap on n elements.
>
> Proof - A reasonably straightforward enumeration shows that there are $H(n)=
> n !/\prod t_i$ valid heaps on a set on n numbers where $t_i$ is the size of the heap rooted at
>   node $i$. A lower bound on the average number of comparisons required to permit one
>   of $n!$ possible input sequences to one of these orders is $$\lg(n!/H(n))=\sum \lg t_i.$$

I understand how the number of valid heap is calculated. But I don't know information theory so I can't see how the last equation is the lower bound. Is there any theorem or book I can check to see how this works?

Comment: Maybe you can try [Computer Science beta](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).